# What is the difference between bind variables and substitution variables(which I input using &&)?

Tags: oracle, variables, plsql, declaration, sqlplus

What is the difference between these two variable declarations?

1: `num number:='&&num';`
2: `variable num1 number;`

Since in both cases I can reference `num` by using `&num` or `&&num` in other files also, 
and in the case of bind variables `:num1`.

Moreover I have one more confusion: whether any of the below statements differ somehow, are they both valid and do they mean the same thing?

1: `variable num1 number;`
2: `var num1 number;`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You appear to have some confusion about the differences between *bind variables* in Oracle and *substitution variables* in SQL*Plus.

Let's start with substitution variables.  Substitution variables are unique to SQL*Plus and are not part of the database.  They won't work if you try to use them with JDBC, for example.

Substitution variables can only hold a piece of text.  If SQL*Plus encounters a substitution variable in a line of input, it will replace the variable with its text contents:

```
SQL> define subvar=X
SQL> select * from dual where dummy = &subvar;
old   1: select * from dual where dummy = &subvar
new   1: select * from dual where dummy = X
select * from dual where dummy = X
                                 *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "X": invalid identifier
```

Note that SQL*Plus replaced our substitution variable with its text value with no regard  for whether it gave us valid SQL.  In the example above, we omitted the single quotes around `&subvar` and it gave us invalid SQL, so we got an error.

The lines beginning `old` and `new` show us the line we entered before and after SQL*Plus applied the substitution variables.  The `new` line is the line the database tried to run.

You can enable or disable the display of the `old` and `new` lines using `SET VERIFY ON` and `SET VERIFY OFF`.  You can also turn the replacement of substitution variables on or off by using `SET DEFINE ON` and `SET DEFINE OFF`.

If we want to run the above query using the substitution variable, we must put quotes around it:

```
SQL> select * from dual where dummy = '&subvar';
old   1: select * from dual where dummy = '&subvar'
new   1: select * from dual where dummy = 'X'

D
-
X
```

If `&subvar` happens to contain a string that was a valid number (e.g. `5`), then we can get away without using the quotes, but that's only because taking out the text `&subvar` and replacing it with the text `5` happens to give us valid SQL.

For example, suppose we have a table called `test` with the following data in it:

```
         A
----------
         1
         2
         3
         4
         5
```

Then we can do

```
SQL> define subvar=5
SQL> select * from test where a = &subvar;
old   1: select * from test where a = &subvar
new   1: select * from test where a = 5

         A
----------
         5
```

Bind variables, on the other hand, have types.  They are not simple text values.  Their values are sent to the database, and the database can also set their values.

```
SQL> variable bindvar varchar2(1);
SQL> exec :bindvar := 'X';

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

You don't put quotes around a bind variable when you want to use it:

```
SQL> select * from dual where dummy = :bindvar;

D
-
X

SQL> select * from dual where dummy = ':bindvar';

no rows selected
```

In the second example above, we got no rows returned because the `DUAL` table has no rows with the `DUMMY` column containing the text `:bindvar`.

You'll get an error if you attempt to assign a value of the wrong type to a bind variable:

```
SQL> variable bindvar number;
SQL> exec :bindvar := 'X';
BEGIN :bindvar := 'X'; END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character to number conversion error
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

Bind variables are a standard part of the database, and you can use them with JDBC or whichever method of connecting to the database you choose.

---

Finally, `variable num1 number` and `var num1 number` both mean the same thing.  They both define a bind variable `num1` of type `number`.  `var` is just an abbreviation for `variable`.