# What is the difference between PLSQL Bind variables and Host variables

Tags: oracle, plsql

With respect to PLSQL, what is the difference between a 'Host Variable' and a 'Bind Variable'?

This [link](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1063759517155) from askTom  says that "the distinction blurs in plsql -- its very close to sql". Then what is that tiny, 'blurry' difference?

Statement 1:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE dummy = :B1;
```

Statement 2:

```
SELECT 1 FROM dual WHERE dummy = v_var;
```

In these two statements, Statement 1 represents a bind variable and Statement 2 represents a Host variable, am I correct?

Comment: Bind/Host Variable applies only for `embedded SQL/PLSQL`... `Bind` is actually sending some value from your interface(Java or Pro*C) to Oracle.. And `Host` is the variable define in your interface and get its value from Oracle... So your statement goes absurd. Any _static_ SQL in the `PL/SQL` blocks using variables itself, would be implicitly used in the way similar to bind variables.. (Actually the parsed SQL/Plan..) .. hence, With PL/SQL(Executed in Oracle directly and not via JDBC or any OCI based) there's _NO_ bind variables literally.. Unless you have a dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this snippet of C#:

```
int    v_empno = 7369;
string v_ename;

OracleCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
cmd.Parameters.Add("paramEmpno", OracleDbType.Decimal, v_empno, ParameterDirection.Input);
cmd.CommandText = "select e.ename from scott.emp e where e.empno = :1";
v_ename = cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
```

`v_empno` and `v_ename` are host variables. Here you explicitly create your bind variable for use as `:1` in your the statement.

Consider this snippet of PL/SQL:

```
declare
   v_empno  number := 7369;
   v_ename  varchar2(10);
begin
   select e.ename
     into v_ename
     from scott.emp e
    where e.empno = v_empno;
   dbms_output.put_line(v_ename);
end;
/
```

Again the declared variables `v_empno` and `v_ename` can be considered host variables, but when they are used in static SQL within the PL/SQL code, they are automatically turned into bind variables by the PL/SQL compiler/engine - you do not have to manually create your bind variable like in the C# example. If you examine the SQL that is actually executed by this piece of PL/SQL, it will look something like this:

```
   select e.ename
     from scott.emp e
    where e.empno = :B1
```

That is the PL/SQL compiler that automatically has created `:B1` bind variable for your `v_empno` PL/SQL variable. And that is what Tom Kyte means that you cannot really make a proper distinction between host variable and bind variable in PL/SQL. When you write PL/SQL the variables are host variables when used in PL/SQL code and at the same time they are bind variables when used in the embedded SQL code. You do not need to make a distinction in PL/SQL, the compiler takes care of it for you.

Answer (score 3):

As per [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a97269/pc_04dat.htm#27300)

Host variables are the key to communication between your host program and Oracle. Typically, a precompiler program inputs data from a host variable to Oracle, and Oracle outputs data to a host variable in the program. Oracle stores input data in database columns, and stores output data in program host variables.

A host variable can be any arbitrary C expression that resolves to a scalar type. But, a host variable must also be an lvalue. Host arrays of most host variables are also supported.

[Bind variables](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_bind_variables.html) are not simple text values. Their values are sent to the database, and the database can also set their values.  PL/SQL itself takes care of most of the issues to do with bind variables. Every reference to a PL/SQL variable is in fact a bind variable.

**For example:**

```
int     empno; 
char    ename[10]; 
float   sal; 
... 
EXEC SQL SELECT ename, sal INTO :ename, :sal FROM emp 
     WHERE empno = :empno; 

empno, ename, sal are all Host variables
:empno, :ename, :sal are all bind variables
```

You can see a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7782802/what-is-the-difference-between-bind-variables-and-the-variable-which-i-input-usi)

Comment: This documentation refers to Pro*C/C++ Precompiler. I don't think that the term "HOST VARIABLE" is applicable to PL/SQL at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, but , as @Rusty pointed out, it refers to Pro*C/C++ Precompiler and not PLSQL

Answer (score 2):

Bind/Host Variable applies only for `embedded SQL/PLSQL`...

`Bind` is actually sending some value from your interface(Java or Pro*C) to Oracle..

`Host` is the variable defined in your interface and get its value from Oracle...

So your statement goes absurd.

Any *static* SQL in the `PL/SQL` blocks using variables itself, would be implicitly used in the way similar to bind variables..

> --It means next execution of this SQL could re-use the plan and
>   cursor would be shared.. in case of Adaptive cursor sharing..

.. hence, With PL/SQL(Executed in Oracle directly and not via JDBC or any OCI based) there's *NO* bind variables literally.. Unless you have a dynamic SQL.

**Example :**

```
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NAME FROM EMP WHERE ID = : ID' USING V_MYID
```

Here `:ID` is Bind Variable ---- (To Accept Value to the Query from the caller)
and `V_MYID` is Host Variable.....(Defined in the caller/host itself)

The concept is similar to other Embedded SQL principles..