# i have several errors of PLS-00049

Tags: plsql

cursor is there to check for eligibility in student. however i cant even compile the script as i keep getting several of error:

> [Error] PLS-00049 (395: 46): PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'SORLCUR_PIDM'.

```
CURSOR C_ENSP IS
  SELECT SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE 
           ,STVESTS_DESC
                FROM STVESTS,SFRENSP
                WHERE SFRENSP_PIDM = :Sorlcur_PIDM
                AND SFRENSP_TERM_CODE = :sorlcur_TERM_CODE
                AND SFRENSP_KEY_SEQNO = :SORLCUR_KEY_SEQNO
                AND STVESTS_CODE = SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE;

                CURSOR C_ENSP_SECOND IS
  SELECT   'Y'
  FROM SORLCUR, SFRENSP
  WHERE SORLCUR_PIDM = :Sorlcur_PIDM
  and  SORLCUR_PIDM = SFRENSP_PIDM
  AND sorlcur_TERM_CODE = :sorlcur_TERM_CODE
  AND  sorlcur_TERM_CODE   =  SFRENSP_TERM_CODE
  AND SORLCUR_CURRENT_CDE = 'Y'
  AND SORLCUR_CACT_CODE = 'ACTIVE'
  AND SORLCUR_LMOD_CODE = 'LEARNER'
  AND SORLCUR_PRIORITY_NO = 2
  AND SFRENSP_KEY_SEQNO = SORLCUR_KEY_SEQNO
  AND SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE NOT IN ( 'W', 'X' , 'Z');

  v_ENSP_SECOND   VARCHAR2(1);

  CURSOR c_cohort IS
  SELECT chrt.sgrchrt_chrt_code
  FROM sgrchrt chrt 
  WHERE sgrchrt_pidm = :sorlcur_pidm   
  AND NVL(chrt.sgrchrt_stsp_key_sequence,99999999) =  :sorlcur_key_seqno  
  AND NVL(sgrchrt_term_code_eff,'~') =  :stvterm_term_code;

  CURSOR c_resd IS
  SELECT sgbstdn_resd_code,stvresd_desc
  FROM   sgbstdn,stvresd
  WHERE  SGBSTDN_PIDM  = :KEY_BLOCK.PIDM
  AND    SGBSTDN_TERM_CODE_EFF = :KEY_BLOCK.STVTERM_TERM_CODE
  AND    stvresd_code = sgbstdn_resd_code;

  cursor c1 is 
  select skricas_cas_number,
       skricas_cas_status
  from    skricas a              
  where  a.SKRICAS_PIDM = :key_block.PIDM
  and exists (select 'x' from sorlcur
            where sorlcur_pidm = skricas_pidm
            and sorlcur_seqno  = skricas_lcur_seqno
            and sorlcur_term_code = :key_block.stvterm_term_code)
  and skricas_cas_status = 'USED'
  and skricas_cas_exp_date = (select max(a1.skricas_cas_exp_date)
                            from   skricas a1
                            where  a1.skricas_pidm = a.skricas_pidm
                            and    a1.skricas_cas_status = a.skricas_cas_status
                           );

-- TT06987 start
   CURSOR get_JSopt_in IS
      SELECT  szrasop_opt_in
      FROM    szrasop
      WHERE   szrasop_pidm = :sorlcur.Sorlcur_PIDM
      AND szrasop_term_code = :sorlcur.Sorlcur_TERM_CODE;

  ---  v_elig   VARCHAR2(1);  

   CURSOR get_max_szrolps IS    
    SELECT MAX( SZROLPS_SEQ_NO)
                  FROM   SATURN.SZROLPS
                  WHERE  SZROLPS_PIDM = :sorlcur.Sorlcur_PIDM
    AND    SZROLPS_TERM_CODE = :sorlcur.Sorlcur_TERM_CODE;

    v_max_stage  szrolps.szrolps_seq_no%TYPE;

-- TT06987 end   

   BEGIN

                IF :sorlcur_program IS NOT NULL THEN
                                :SORLCUR_SMRPCMT_TEXT := F_UOG_GET_COMMENT(:sorlcur_program, :sorlcur_term_code, 'PRGTIT');
                                OPEN C_ENSP;
                                FETCH C_ENSP INTO :SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE, :ESTS_DESCRIPTION;
                                CLOSE C_ENSP;

                                OPEN C_ENSP_SECOND;
                                FETCH C_ENSP_SECOND INTO v_ENSP_SECOND ;
                                IF C_ENSP_SECOND%NOTFOUND THEN
                                                :secondary_prog := 'N';
                                ELSE
                                                :secondary_prog := 'Y';
                                END IF; 
                                CLOSE C_ENSP_SECOND;

                END IF;

                OPEN c_cohort;
                FETCH c_cohort
                INTO  :ENTRY_COHORT;
                CLOSE  c_cohort;

  OPEN  c_resd;
  FETCH c_resd
  INTO  :sgbstdn_resd_code,:stvresd_desc;
  CLOSE c_resd;

                SELECT STVATTS_DESC
                INTO   :mode_desc
  FROM   STVATTS
  WHERE  :sorlcur_mode_code = STVATTS.STVATTS_CODE 
  AND    STVATTS.STVATTS_CODE LIKE 'M%';

  select stvstyp_desc
  into   :sorlcur.styp_desc
  from   stvstyp
  where  :SORLCUR_STYP_CODE = stvstyp_code;

  :sorlcur.SITE_DESC := gb_stvsite.f_get_description(:SORLCUR_SITE_CODE);




  get_last_section_completed;
-- added by Mary for 5095
                open c1;
                fetch c1 into :cas_number,
                              :cas_status;
close c1;


-- TT06987 start
   -- Student eligible??
   IF hwzkimag.F_eligible_js (:sorlcur.Sorlcur_PIDM,   :sorlcur.sorlcur_TERM_CODE)
   THEN
    :optin_elig := 'Y';
   END IF;

--message(:optin_elig);message(:optin_elig);
   IF NVL(:optin_elig,'XXX') = 'Y' THEN

     OPEN               get_max_szrolps;
     FETCH  get_max_szrolps
     INTO   v_max_stage;
     CLOSE  get_max_szrolps;

     -- ELigible and got passed the opt in / opt out stage 7.
     IF v_max_stage >= 7 THEN

                 OPEN  get_JSopt_in;
                   FETCH get_JSopt_in
       INTO  :optin_yes;
       CLOSE get_JSopt_in;
                  set_item_property('jsopt_message',visible,property_false);
     -- Eligible but has not passed opt in / opt out stage 7. 
     ELSE         
        :jsopt_message := 'OLR not complete';
                  set_item_property('jsopt_message',visible,property_true);
     END IF;
   END IF;  
-- TT06987 end
```

Comment: once i take off ' : ' from :sorlcur_PIDM, then i get a invalid identifier error, i also checked my tables with the column name and there isnt any difference.

Comment: post your full code or something which give an overview of what you are trying to do

Comment: @XING .. I've edited the post with full code

Answer (score 0):

i've solved the problem. There were two errors in the below code. 1st is bad bind variable and 2nd is invalid identifier.

```
CURSOR C_ENSP IS
      SELECT SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE 
               ,STVESTS_DESC
                    FROM STVESTS,SFRENSP
                    WHERE SFRENSP_PIDM = :Sorlcur_PIDM
                    AND SFRENSP_TERM_CODE = :sorlcur_TERM_CODE
                    AND SFRENSP_KEY_SEQNO = :SORLCUR_KEY_SEQNO
                    AND STVESTS_CODE = SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE;
```

1st - i took out the colons on the columns name (e.g. :sorlcur_pidm to just sorlcur_pidm)
2nd - the table name sorlcur wasnt defined as i was calling table columns from 3 different tables.

-- The correct Syntax is below --

```
CURSOR C_ENSP IS
          SELECT SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE 
                   ,STVESTS_DESC
                        FROM STVESTS,SFRENSP,SORLCUR
                        WHERE SFRENSP_PIDM = Sorlcur_PIDM
                        AND SFRENSP_TERM_CODE = sorlcur_TERM_CODE
                        AND SFRENSP_KEY_SEQNO = SORLCUR_KEY_SEQNO
                        AND STVESTS_CODE = SFRENSP_ESTS_CODE;
```

Comment: As you've discovered, PL/SQL variables don't have any prefix. `:` indicates a bind or host variable, which is not what you want here. (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256597/what-is-the-difference-between-plsql-bind-variables-and-host-variables)